# Hide a div without specificing the id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching on a question like this but I cant find it.

I have structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="productholder@(item.ProductId)" class="productholder">  
  <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image)" alt="" />
  <div class="productinfo">
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h2>
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.Description)</p>
    <br />   
  </div>
  <div class="productprice">     
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price):-</h2>          
    <input type="button" value="Ta bort" class="b" data-ProductImageId='@item.ProductImageId'>                          
  </div>                                   
</div>
```

What I want to do is that when somebody click on the button that has `class="b"` the whole div tag should get hidden with `.hide()` the problem is that I have 10 of these div tags that look the same so I cant specify a div tag, because its important that just the div tag inside the button that i clicked gets hidden.

I guess I need to use parent or something like that?

I have tried the following jquery scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".b").click(function () {
            $("div:eq(0)").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I figure out it wont work beacuse it will hide the whole div wrapper.

Any kind of solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
```

or

```
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to hide the whole container.. try using `closest`

```
$(this).closest('.productholder').hide()
```

or If you are just trying to hide the parent div, then simply use `.parent()`

```
$(this).parent().hide()
```

**Full code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.productholder').hide();
        // or $(this).parent().hide()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just hide the button's parent:

```
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(this).parent('div').hide();
    });
```

Or, if you want to make sure the div get hidden even if you change the hierarchy a little bit:

```
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('div.productprice').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic DOM: Every dom node has a parent element:

```
$('.b').click(function() {
   $(this).parent('div.productprice').hide();
});
```